# Apply own activation function to layer in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, activation-function

I'm using a model where the tensorflow relu function is used for the activation of the hidden layers. So basically the model does this

```
h = tf.nn.relu(zw)
```

where zw are all the elements from the output from the previous layer times weights. According to the definition of relu of tensorflow it will return

```
max(zw,0)
```

so the max number between 0 and the value of each element of zw for each element of the tensor.

How can I apply my own relu function where I return the element zw if it is above 0 and the zw element times 0.1 if it is smaller than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

h = tf.where(zw < 0, 0.1 * zw, zw)